# Oracle apex_web_service.make_rest_request error

Tags: rest, oracle-apex, oracle19c

[image]

I had created the ACL and also granted the privileges and it's giving me an error.

[image]

Below is the pl/sql block which is working fine on apex.oracle.com and inserting the data in the table, but when I call same pl/sql block from my database it gives an error. Please let me know whare I am mistaken.

Database 19c
apex: 22.2

```
DECLARE
  l_respclob CLOB;
  l_reqbody CLOB;
  v_access_token VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_Status VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';


  apex_json.initialize_clob_output;
  apex_json.open_object;

  l_reqbody :=
    '{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "2KDLXfdDZAKdeRivIg4",
    "client_secret": "UqPvcfZ43yVbF0QlC58PcVYkSuSr6sTW88QTPUTEb56BGoH19goIj2Zzzxl"
}';

  l_respclob :=
    apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
      p_url => 'https://git-ss.piwik.pro/auth/token',
      p_http_method => 'POST',
      p_body => l_reqbody
    );

  v_access_token := JSON_VALUE(l_respclob, '$.access_token');

  insert into TBL_MAKE_REQ(TOKEN)
  values (v_access_token);
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the network ACL to the APEX Engine user, i.e. APEX_NNNNNN, see the APEX Installation Guide: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmig/enabling-network-services-in-Oracle-db11g-or-later.html#GUID-8D125731-989A-4A51-AFFE-00181729F87F

Comment: I had createACL to with '*', localhost and IP as per the document. but showing same error

Comment: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1230
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 804
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.

Comment: which database user did you grant to?